# How do I subtract the quantity of my products listed in listbox directly to my database of products? (MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

First of all, I am not really into hard coding and such, I really did try to search for a solution to my problem but I am not getting some of the explanation. Or maybe it is not the way I code mine so I cannot understand.

Technically I have 3 lisboxes for the quantity, product name, and price of the product. When a product is added on a cart, it automatically lists down in the listbox.

I am trying to subtract the quantity of the product stocks saved in the database, to the number of products listed on the cart.

My code works when I only buy one product, but when I am trying to buy 2 or more products, nothing gets subtracted to the database of my products.

PS. Sorry if ever I incorrectly posted my question, it is just my first time posting here. Thank you in advance!

```
string item = string.Empty;
int quantity = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= LBItemName.Items.Count - 1; i++) {
    item += Convert.ToString(LBItemName.Items[i]); }

for (int j = 0; j <= LBItemQuantity.Items.Count - 1; j++) {
    quantity += Convert.ToInt32(LBItemQuantity.Items[j]); }

MySqlCommand tryCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE QuizonVet.Product SET numberofstocks=(numberofstocks-'" + quantity + "') where productname='" + item + "';", myConnection);

myReader = tryCommand.ExecuteReader();
myReader.Close();
```

Comment: If you use debugger to see how the command string looks like when you have 2 or more items, it should be pretty clear. What you want is for each product sold, you want to reduce the amount in database by the corresponding quantity. Let's say I buy 2 apple and 3 orange, item become `"appleorange"` and quantity become 5. The result is you are trying to deduct the quantity by 5 for item with name `"appleorange"` which does not exists thus nothing change in your database.

Comment: The simplest way is really just update your database once for every item since different item can update the value differently.

Comment: I see. I finally get how my code really works. Thanks for that...But isn't there a one button click away from what I want my system to do? Isn't it if I do it one item at a time, making it a "shopping cart" will be pointless?

Comment: I can't think of 1 simple way of doing that other than using case statement

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a couple of problems going on here

First being the `Sql` `Update` statement should be in the format like this

> UPDATE QuizonVet.Product SET numberofstocks=(numberofstocks-123) where
>   productname='someProduct'

Im assuming each item in the the list corrosponds to exactly to the index in the other lists

In your code were trying to add multiple products together, how would it know what value updates what product? at best it would look like this...

> UPDATE QuizonVet.Product SET numberofstocks=(numberofstocks-123 324 345) where
>   productname='someProduct someProduct someProduct'

So i guess what you can do is make a new `sql` for each item in the product list and get its corresponding quantity

Disclaimer i haven't tested this

**Code**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= LBItemName.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var item = Convert.ToString(LBItemName.Items[i]);
    var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(LBItemQuantity.Items[i]);
    MySqlCommand tryCommand = new MySqlCommand($"UPDATE QuizonVet.Product SET numberofstocks=(numberofstocks-{quantity}) where productname='{item}'", myConnection);
    myReader = tryCommand.ExecuteReader();
    myReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have fixed some of the errors in the code but what's happening now is that the quantities add then it subtracts to each of the products.

Comment: What do you mean it adds then subtracts. (numberofstocks-{quantity}) should just minus the current quantity from numberofstocks. i'm just trying to understand what you are seeing

Comment: For example is, I bought 2 apples and 3 oranges. 

Then in my database, what happens is that 5 apples and 5 oranges where subtracted into my database of products.

I'm really sorry if I find it hard to explain.

Comment: Yeah i think i might be misunderstanding how your program works with the lists, are the lists synchronized, ie does element 1 of the LBItemName list (ProductName) correlate to element 1 in the LBItemQuantity list (quantity)